# Java & HSQLDB INSERT TO problem

Tags: java, insert, hsqldb

I've a problem when I try to insert data into a hsqldb with a Java class :
The code is :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.ParseException;




     public class Main {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
             try {
                 Connection con = null;
                 String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:../db/db";
                 Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
                 con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "sa", null);
                 Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                 Statement stm1 = con.createStatement();

                 statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO \"vacDeGroupe\"(\"type\") VALUES ('test')");
                 ResultSet rs = stm1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM \"vacDeGroupe\"");
                 while(rs.next()) {
                     System.out.println(rs.getString("type"));
                 }

                 stm1.close();
                 statement.close();
                 con.close();

             }
             catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {

             } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

        }
```

If I exec this code I have my entries + the new I have INSERT INTO my database.
But, after if I only do the executeQuery(), the row I have insert is not in my database.
I've checked, autoCommit is on true.

... I don't understand what's happened.

(I'm french so I'm sorry if there is some english errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executeUpdate` for INSERT, not `executeQuery`.  And it does not return a `ResultSet`; it's number of affected rows.

Comment: Thank's I've change that but this was just a mistake introduce during my tests to find why it doesn't work.
Problem is still the same : when I execute the "insert to" AND the executeQuery it works I can read the new line I have insert, but when (after I've executed the code to insert the line) I execute only the executeQuery I have all the table without the line I have insert before.
So I think there is a problem during the insert into the table but I don't understand where and why...
I hope you understand the problem.

Comment: OK, finaly I find the answer in an other post :

I've to launch the connexion with two options :

    hsqldb.write_delay=false
    shutdown=true
So I add them in my String url :

    String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:file:../db/db;hsqldb.write_delay=false;shutdown=true";
And it works !